# batch file to search for text and write it to a text file

Tags: batch-file

I have a large(20MB) text (input) file with various lines of text (including blank lines) in it.  I would like a batch file that can find specific text in the input file, grab the string the search term is in, write that string to another text (output) file AND append that string with a space, comma and the line that follows it in the input file in the output file.

1. INPUT FILE DATA:

   ```
   NORTHING         EASTING   O-HEIGHT     CODE FFF STATION   STD DEV MAPPROJ
   ```

   ---

   NEO  000 020720618         4829559.470     ,12082011c.lst

   0.015            0.015      0.015
   NEO  000 020740188         4835430.827     ,12082011c.lst

   0.009            0.009      0.009
   NEO  000 020750232         4841535.651     ,12082011c.lst

   0.004            0.004      0.004
   PLH  000 020720615    N 43 36  15.44568 W 79 32  38.22754       67.892 m       0     ,12082011c.lst

   0.014             0.014        0.014                    ,12082011c.lst
2. SEARCH TERM: "NEO"
3. OUTPUT:

   NEO  000 020720618         4829559.470     ,12082011c.lst,     0.015            0.015      0.015
   NEO  000 020740188         4835430.827     ,12082011c.lst,     0.009            0.009      0.009
   NEO  000 020750232         4841535.651     ,12082011c.lst,     0.004            0.004      0.004

I've tried using the findstr command and it will write the first part of the line ( NEO  000 020720618         4829559.470     ,12082011c.lst) but I can't figure out how to grab the next line and append it to the string. (the strings are longer than I've shown in this example so if there is a character limit for variables please let me know).
Thanks,
Gabe.

Comment: Batch is not a good choice for text processing. It could be done, but it will be convoluted and probably unacceptably slow. If you want to use native Windows scripting tools then you would be much better off using PowerShell, VBScript, or JScript. If you are allowed to use 3rd party tools then a utility like sed for Windows would be perfect. (Gnu has a free port of sed for Windows)

Comment: Also, batch can only process lines up to 8191 bytes long. (actually a bit less, but the exact value depends on the code)

Comment: Thanks very much for your feedback.  I did get the feeling I was walking into convoluted territory.  I'm attepmting the batch route because it is easily available but I can see it has it's limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I indicated in my comment, batch is not a good choice for processing text files. But here is a native batch solution for your problem. I am assuming you are searching for lines where the first token is NEO, not for lines that contain NEO anywhere within.

It looks like you want to ignore the empty lines, which is good because FOR /F ignores empty lines.

This solution will also ignore any line that begins with `;` due to the default FOR /F EOL option. This can be eliminated by setting EOL to a linefeed character, but the [syntax](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=10729) is ugly. I am assuming you do not have lines that begin with `;`.

As with any batch solution, lines are limited to ~8191 bytes.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "ln1="
>"output.txt" (
  for /f "useback delims=" %%A in ("input.txt") do (
    if defined ln1 (
      set "ln2=%%A"
      setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
      echo(!ln1! ,!ln2!
      endlocal
      set "ln1="
    )
    for /f %%B in ("%%A") do if "%%B"=="NEO" set "ln1=%%A"
  )
)
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Your assumptions are correct. Thank you very much.